# How to fix Index 9 out of bounds for length 9 for TicTacToe method

Tags: java

```
    boolean checkHorz(int boardSpace) {
    for (int i=0; i<(int)java.lang.Math.sqrt(boardSpace); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<((int)java.lang.Math.sqrt(boardSpace)-1); j++) {
            if (data[i * boardSpace + j].equals(data[i * boardSpace + j + 1]) && !data[i * boardSpace + j].equals("_")) {
                matchingX += 1;
            } else matchingX = 0;
        }
    }
    if (matchingX == boardSpace-1) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}
```

I am making TicTacToe program where you can enter the X-by-X on the board which multiplied is boardSpace. When tested out the method with a boardSpace of 9 (standard tic tac toe board) it gave me a "Index 9 out of bounds for length 9" error. (Note: matchingX increments when a space and the one immediately right of it matches).

Comment: You're multiplying your index by `boardSpace` (i.e. the *length* of the array) then indexing into the array with it. Any nonzero index is going to crash on that line.

Comment: Why are you using a one-dimensional array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indexing by multiplying by `boardSize` which happens to be 9.. So `(i * 9 + j)` when `i > 0` will go out of bounds for an array of length 9.

Also, first you should do the square root check just once like:

```java
int size = (int)java.lang.Math.sqrt(boardSpace);
```

Then you'd have your loop like:

```java
for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < size; ++column)
    {
        char value = data[row * size + column];
        //....
    }
}
```

To check for row vs. column, just flip the indexing order:

```java
char row_value = data[row * size + column];
char column_value = data[column * size + row];
```